Handle multiple text boxes together
I have a sub which creates a number (n) of textboxes in a worksheet.
Sub CreateShapes()
Dim sOrd As String
Dim n As Integer
Const iBr = 67

  sOrd = Selection.Text
  
  For n = 1 To Len(sOrd)
  
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 50 + iBr * n, 150 _
        , 200, 70).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Mid(sOrd, n, 1)
  Next n

End Sub

When the sub is finished, the last textbox is selected. How can I select all the n textboxes to group them?
I have tried to find out how to use ShapeRange, but haven't managed.

Are there other shapes in the respective worksheet?

Yes, there may be.

Then, you should use the answer you received, declare the existing variable as suggested, or change the last code line replacing selected_shapes with `new_range'. Then, mark the answer as accepted one...

Sorry, I get the same error message. I do not use Option Explicit.

You really should use
Option Explicit for VBA coding.

If there are only the created shapes on the sheet:
Sub CreateShapes()
Dim sOrd As String
Dim n As Integer
Dim selected_shapes As ShapeRange
Const iBr = 67

  sOrd = Selection.Text
  
  For n = 1 To Len(sOrd)
  
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 50 + iBr * n, 150 _
        , 200, 70).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Mid(sOrd, n, 1)
  Next n
  
  
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
  Set selected_shapes = Selection.ShapeRange

End Sub



If there are previously created shapes on the sheet then:
Sub CreateShapes()
Dim sOrd As String
Dim n As Integer
Const iBr = 67
Dim selected_shapes As ShapeRange
  sOrd = Selection.Text
ReDim shape_index(1 To Len(sOrd)) As Long
  
  For n = 1 To Len(sOrd)
  
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 50 + iBr * n, 150 _
        , 200, 70).Select
    shape_index(n) = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Mid(sOrd, n, 1)
  Next n
  
  
  
  Set selected_shapes = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(shape_index)

End Sub




There may be other shapes in the worksheet. I have tested the second sub, but it gives error 424 Object required on the last line.

Sorry. I have tried both. Where should the last one be inserted?

Sorry, I get the same error message. I do not use Option Explicit.

Sorry, I don't know how, but the qualifier was left out. Set selected_shapes = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(shape_index). Edited also in the post.

Only the last text box is still selected. I want code like this, where "TextBox x" is substituted with a variable (1 to n) :
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 5", "TextBox 6", "TextBox 7", _
"TextBox 8")).Select

Then select them like this:  selected_shapes.Select
